# What mix of cement and sand should I use to set cap slabs?

Tags: walls, mortar

We have a number of "slabs" that are just wider than a brick, which are set on top of walls in the garden. A number of them have come lose and I need to remove the cement mix that used to hold them down and set them again.

What mix of cement and sand should I use, and are there other things I should mix in to ensure the mortar has a good "grip" on the stone that sits on top of the wall?

Comment: Construction adhesive works well.

Comment: Would "Construction Adhesive" be available in a hardware store (in the UK I'm thinking Wickes, Jewsons, B&Q)? Is it something that's added to the cement and sand mix?

Comment: I'm not sure what is available in the UK, in the states it would be Liquid Nails, or a construction adhesive from DAP. This is not mixed with the cement, it is used to glue the top cap to the wall.

Comment: Could you add that as an answer rather than a comment so I can accept it as the answer. Otherwise I'll add it myself but you should get the rep points for answering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a Construction adhesive like [Liquid Nails](http://www.liquidnails.com/diy/index.jsp) or [Beats the Nail](http://www.dap.com/product_details.aspx?BrandID=80&SubcatID=11).  This works well for cap stones, since they are usually not a structural part of the wall.